# How to establish authentication in apache or nginx based on my rails application?

Tags: apache, authentication, nginx, token

I would like to limit access to some resources provided by my apache server. e.g. images and videos. The main web-application managing the users runs on ruby on rails.

Now I would like to let apache check whether the access request is valid.

The user should provide an authentication token, he received from my rails app, so apache can grant or reject the access to the files.

It would be best, if the request could look like this:
    http://myserver.com/filexyz.mp4?token=jhg987gojhg876

Are there some approaches for this?

Maybe an nginx module?

Comment: Ha! I found it: http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/
does exactly what I was looking for.
The rails app and the module share the same key for token generation, so that the access to a resource can be restricted outside a time window and to a specific IP.